# ¿Como configurar DbContext para nombre de tablas en singular?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Estoy empezando a trabajar con MVC 5 y Entity Framework 6, aclaro de antemano que en mi proyecto no estoy usando los asistentes de visual studio para EF ya que quiero entender a fondo como funciona. Pues bien, mi problema viene al leer una tabla de mi base de datos.

En SQL Server tengo mi estructura de la siguiente manera:

```
TABLE [dbo].[Usuario](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Apellidos] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [TipoAreaId] [int] NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Status] [tinyint] NULL,
```

En Visual Studio he creado mi clase:

```
public class Usuario
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }
        public int TipoAreaId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public EStatus Status { get; set; }
        public enum EStatus { Eliminado = 0, Activo = 1 }

    }
```

Ahora bien mi DbContext de EntityFramework es el siguiente:

```
public class AlbatrosDB: DbContext
    {
        public AlbatrosDB() : base("AlbatrosDB")
        {Database.SetInitializer<AlbatrosDB>(null);}

        public DbSet<Usuario> UsuarioDB { get; set; }
    }
```

En mi controller la consulta tipo LINQ es asi:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(Login mdl)
        {
            AlbatrosDB conn = new AlbatrosDB();

            var Usuario = conn.UsuarioDB.SingleOrDefault(dbo => dbo.Email == mdl.Email 
            && dbo.Password == mdl.Password
            && dbo.Status == Models.Administracion.Usuario.EStatus.Activo);

            if (Usuario != null)
            {
                MostrarMensaje(Mensaje.Tipo.Correcto, "Login Correcto");
                return View("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                MostrarMensaje(Mensaje.Tipo.Alerta, "Datos de inicio de sesión no válidos.");
                return View("Index");
            }
        }
```

Al ejecutar mi aplicación obtengo el siguiente error:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. Invalid object name
>   'dbo.Usuarios'.
>
> Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la
>   solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener
>   más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid
>   object name 'dbo.Usuarios'.
>
> Error de código fuente:
>
> Línea 24:             AlbatrosDB conn = new AlbatrosDB(); Línea 25: 
>   Línea 26:             var Usuario = conn.UsuarioDB.SingleOrDefault(dbo
>   => dbo.Email == mdl.Email  Línea 27:             && dbo.Password == mdl.Password Línea 28:             && dbo.Status ==
>   Models.Administracion.Usuario.EStatus.Activo);

En el error me doy cuenta que el Entity Framework esta agregando una 's' al nombre de mi tabla, lo cual es falso, en algunos foros estuve leyendo que se trata de una configuración del nombre de las tablas (En singular o plural), sin embargo no he encontrado información acerca de como puedo hacer dicha configuración manualmente.

Espero puedan ayudarme amigos y de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por defecto EF pluraliza los nombres de la tabla, es por ello el error. En tu clase `Usuario` agrega los siguiente:

```
[Table("Usuario")]
public class Usuario
```

O mediante Fluent Api en tu contexto `AlbatrosDB`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
  .ToTable("Usuario");
}
```